# Put checkboxes next to added options

Tags: html, css, checkbox, sass, alignment

Right now the code I'm using in html is:

```
<label name="diet" for="">Dieet:</label>
  @foreach($diets as $diet)
      <p> {{ $diet->titel }} </p>

      <input type="checkbox" id="diet[]" for="diet[]" name="diet[]" value="{{ $diet->id }}" class="dieet{{ $diet->id }}">
```

In CSS the code is

```
#form_new_recipe


    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width:min-content;
        color: white;

        label{
            display: block;
        }

        input, textarea{
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        display: block;
        }

        input[type="text"], textarea{
            margin-top:20px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            display: block;
            width: 600px;
        }
    }
```

So my question is: How can I see my checkboxes next to the added options? (It's in collaboration with a backend developer)

Also something that's probably even harder, I want to put the added options horizontally aligned next to each other (to a certain extent)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label name="diet" for="">Dieet:</label>
  @foreach($diets as $diet)
<label><input type="checkbox" id="diet[]" for="diet[]" name="diet[]" value="{{ $diet->id }}" class="dieet{{ $diet->id }}">{{$diet->titel}}</label>
```

Do you mean like that? Showing the label next to the input (and its clickable too)

Comment: I still don't see checkboxes :(

Comment: I tried: 

<label name="diet" for="">Dieet:</label>
      @foreach($diets as $diet)
      <input type="checkbox" id="diet[]" for="diet[]" name="diet[]" value="{{ $diet->id }}" class="dieet{{ $diet->id }}"><label>{{$diet->titel}}</label>  

It shows the checkboxes now, but they are non-responsive.

Comment: Im unsure how what I posted would not work but your other way would?

Comment: Because the id should've been the id. The box should be checked to what has the same id. 

Idk why exactly yours wouldn't work either, but I just tried some stuff. The code you gave me did give me some insights, but it didn't work. The checkboxes didn't even appear.

Comment: Because the title should've been the id.*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

```
    <label name="diet" for="">Dieet:</label>
  @foreach($diets as $diet)
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{$diet->titel}}" value="{{ $diet->id }}" ><label for="{{$diet->titel}}">{{$diet->titel}}</label>
```